# In neural networks, why is the bias seen as either a "b" parameter or as an additional "wx" neuron?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

In other words, what is the main reason from switching the bias to a `b_j` or to an additional `w_ij*x_i` in the neuron summation formula before the sigmoid? Performance? **Which method is the best and why?**

*Note: `j` is a neuron of the actual layer and `i` a neuron of a lower layer.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note*: it makes little sense to ask for the `best` method here. Those are two different mathematical notations for exactly the same thing.

However, fitting the bias as just another weight allows you to rewrite the sum as a scalar product of an observed feature vector `x_d` with the weight vector `w`.

Have you tried to calculate the derivate w.r.t `w` in order to get the optimal `w` according to least squares? You will notice that this calculation becomes much cleaner in a vectorized notation.

Apart from that: In many high level programming languages vectorized calculations are significantly more efficient than the non-vectorized equivalent. So performance is also point, at least in some languages.

Comment: When changing the bias into an additional neuron (for performance to do a scalar product), do we lose the individual neurons bias information to share the same bias across the layer of neurons?

Comment: Oh, I see, the external bias neuron does not learn a value, it's weight is adjusted for every neuron of the layer so no information is lost, thanks. Maybe you want to edit your answer to add that!

Comment: You don't change the bias into a neuron, you make the bias part of the weights. Basically you add to each neuron an additional constant input of 1 which is associated to an additional weight. If you do the calculations you will see that this is equivalent to having a bias term for each neuron.

Comment: Yes, that's it (by "changing the bias into an additional neuron", I meant to externalize it into a weighted neuron with a static value of 1). So are each weights to this neuron the "bias" of their linked neuron. Thanks